# get specific value from response.data angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to get specific value from a response, here is my js

```
$scope.cari = function () {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8089/MonitoringAPI/webresources/login?a='+$scope.userid+'&d='+$scope.password).then(function(response){
        $scope.reslogin = response.data;
        $scope.reslogin2 = response.data.lsmenu.idmenu;
        console.log($scope.reslogin);
        console.log($scope.reslogin2);


  });
      };
```

but when i console.log the `$scope.reslogin2`gives me undefined value. here is my response

`[{"userid":"1234",
"username":"ristian",
"posisi":"ITSupport",
"lsmenu":[{"idmenu":"1","parentidmenu":"11","parentnamemenu":"Monitoring","urlmenu":"lalala.html"}]}]`

Comment: try response[0].lsmenu[0]["idmenu"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be, response.data is an array and lsmenu is also an array

```
$scope.reslogin2 = response.data[0].lsmenu[0].idmenu;
```

Comment: or `response[0].lsmenu[0].idmenu`;

Answer (score 1):

According to what you posted, your response is an array (so is the lsmenu). Therefore you should get the first element of the array and also the first element from the lsmenu.

```
$scope.cari = function () {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8089/MonitoringAPI/webresources/login?a='+$scope.userid+'&d='+$scope.password).then(function(response){
    $scope.reslogin = response.data;
    $scope.reslogin2 = response.data[0].lsmenu[0].idmenu;
    console.log($scope.reslogin);
    console.log($scope.reslogin2);


    });
  };
```